# Detect unsaved changes and alert user using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Below is the code so far

```
    <!doctype html>
<html ng-app>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.2/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function Ctrl($scope) {
        var initial = {text: 'initial value'};
        $scope.myModel = angular.copy(initial);
        $scope.revert = function() {
            $scope.myModel = angular.copy(initial);
            $scope.myForm.$setPristine();
        }
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="myForm" ng-controller="Ctrl">
        myModel.text: <input name="input" ng-model="myModel.text">
        <p>myModel.text = {{myModel.text}}</p>
        <p>$pristine = {{myForm.$pristine}}</p>
        <p>$dirty = {{myForm.$dirty}}</p>
        <button ng-click="revert()">Set pristine</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

How to alert on `browser close` or `url redirect` in case there is some unsaved data, so that user can decide whether to continue?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Something like this should do it:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.2/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function Ctrl($scope) {
        var initial = {text: 'initial value'};
        $scope.myModel = angular.copy(initial);
        $scope.revert = function() {
            $scope.myModel = angular.copy(initial);
            $scope.myForm.$setPristine();
        }
    }

    angular.module("myApp", []).directive('confirmOnExit', function() {
        return {
            link: function($scope, elem, attrs) {
                window.onbeforeunload = function(){
                    if ($scope.myForm.$dirty) {
                        return "The form is dirty, do you want to stay on the page?";
                    }
                }
                $scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(event, next, current) {
                    if ($scope.myForm.$dirty) {
                        if(!confirm("The form is dirty, do you want to stay on the page?")) {
                            event.preventDefault();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        };
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="myForm" ng-controller="Ctrl" confirm-on-exit>
        myModel.text: <input name="input" ng-model="myModel.text">
        <p>myModel.text = {{myModel.text}}</p>
        <p>$pristine = {{myForm.$pristine}}</p>
        <p>$dirty = {{myForm.$dirty}}</p>
        <button ng-click="revert()">Set pristine</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Note that the listener for $locationChangeStart isn't triggered in this example since AngularJS doesn't handle any routing in such a simple example, but it should work in an actual Angular application.

Comment: but this thing wont work for browser back button.any hack to get it working?

Comment: Great solution. Simple and efficient!

Comment: Note: for people who are using Angular ui-router, you should use '$stateChangeStart' instead of '$locationChangeStart'. Thanks @Blizzard

Comment: I'd like to suggest following improvement: $scope[element.attr('name')].$dirty So it works for any generic form the directive is used on

Answer (score 34):

I've extended the @Anders answer to clean up listeners (unbind listers) when directive is destroyed (ex: when route changes), and added some syntactic sugar to generalise the usage.

**confirmOnExit Directive**:

```
/**
 * @name confirmOnExit
 * 
 * @description
 * Prompts user while he navigating away from the current route (or, as long as this directive 
 * is not destroyed) if any unsaved form changes present.
 * 
 * @element Attribute
 * @scope
 * @param confirmOnExit Scope function which will be called on window refresh/close or AngularS $route change to
 *                          decide whether to display the prompt or not.
 * @param confirmMessageWindow Custom message to display before browser refresh or closed.
 * @param confirmMessageRoute Custom message to display before navigating to other route.
 * @param confirmMessage Custom message to display when above specific message is not set.
 * 
 * @example
 * Usage:
 * Example Controller: (using controllerAs syntax in this example)
 * 
 *      angular.module('AppModule', []).controller('pageCtrl', [function () {
 *          this.isDirty = function () {
 *              // do your logic and return 'true' to display the prompt, or 'false' otherwise.
 *              return true;
 *          };
 *      }]);
 * 
 * Template:
 * 
 *      <div confirm-on-exit="pageCtrl.isDirty()" 
 *          confirm-message-window="All your changes will be lost."
 *          confirm-message-route="All your changes will be lost. Are you sure you want to do this?">
 * 
 * @see
 * http://stackoverflow.com/a/28905954/340290
 * 
 * @author Manikanta G
 */
ngxDirectivesModule.directive('confirmOnExit', function() {
    return {
        scope: {
            confirmOnExit: '&',
            confirmMessageWindow: '@',
            confirmMessageRoute: '@',
            confirmMessage: '@'
        },
        link: function($scope, elem, attrs) {
            window.onbeforeunload = function(){
                if ($scope.confirmOnExit()) {
                    return $scope.confirmMessageWindow || $scope.confirmMessage;
                }
            }
            var $locationChangeStartUnbind = $scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(event, next, current) {
                if ($scope.confirmOnExit()) {
                    if(! confirm($scope.confirmMessageRoute || $scope.confirmMessage)) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                    }
                }
            });

            $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
                window.onbeforeunload = null;
                $locationChangeStartUnbind();
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Usage:
**Example Controller**: *(using controllerAs syntax in this example)*

```
angular.module('AppModule', []).controller('pageCtrl', [function () {
    this.isDirty = function () {
        // do your logic and return 'true' to display the prompt, or 'false' otherwise.

        return true;
    };
}]);
```

**Template**:

```
<div confirm-on-exit="pageCtrl.isDirty()" 
    confirm-message-window="All your changes will be lost." 
    confirm-message-route="All your changes will be lost. Are you sure you want to do this?">
```

Comment: This is great, but also triggers if the user navigates to an anker on the same page.

Comment: Try this: if (current.split("#")[1] != next.split("#")[1] && $scope.confirmOnExit()) {... I compare the second String of the split array because the first hash is right behind index.html. To be absolutely sure the url contains an anker you have to do some more sophisticated comparison, perhaps with a regex.

Comment: Just a quick note. If you use 'reloadOnSearch' to prevent navigation on $location.search changes, the '$locationChangeStart' event will still pop the dialog, even though the navigation would have been prevented. The '$routeChangeStart' event seems to be a better alternative in this situation.

Comment: What's the best way to ignore clicks coming from a Submit button on a form?

Answer (score 16):

Anders's answer works fine, However, for people who uses Angular ui-router, you should use `'$stateChangeStart'` instead of `'$locationChangeStart'`.

Comment: I've added this as a comment to his answer, thanks @Blizzard

Answer (score 9):

I modified the @Anders answer so that the directive does not contain the form name hard coded:

```
    app.directive('confirmOnExit', function() {
        return {
            link: function($scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
                window.onbeforeunload = function(){
                    if ($scope[attrs["name"]].$dirty) {
                        return "Your edits will be lost.";
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    });
```

Here is the html code for it:

```
<form name="myForm" confirm-on-exit>
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe it will be helpful for someone.
https://github.com/umbrella-web/Angular-unsavedChanges

Using this service you can listen unsaved changes for any object in the scope (not only the form)

Comment: Other directive that works with ui-router
https://github.com/facultymatt/angular-unsavedChanges

Comment: Awesome! but as I see it can listen forms only. Right?

Answer (score 0):

To use [Anders Ekdahl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14853536/940098)'s excellent answer with an Angular 1.5 component, inject the `$scope` in the component's controller:

```
angular
  .module('myModule')
  .component('myComponent', {
    controller: ['$routeParams', '$scope',
      function MyController($routeParams, $scope) {
        var self = this;

        $scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (event, next, current) {
          if (self.productEdit.$dirty && !confirm('There are unsaved changes. Would you like to close the form?')) {
            event.preventDefault();
          }
        });
      }
    ]
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is great, however I had an issue with properly getting a handle on my form controller consistently since some forms I use the `form` tag with the `name` attribute and at other times i use the `ng-form` directive.  Also, if you're using typescript style functions utilizing the `this` or `vm` type pattern e.g. `<form name='$ctrl.myForm'...`

**I'm surprised no one else has mentioned this, but my fix was to utilize the require property of the directive and let angular give me a reference to the form controller itself.**

I've updated the accepted answer below to show my changes, notice the require property and the additional parameter to the link function.

```
angular.module("myApp", []).directive('confirmOnExit', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            require: 'form',
            link: function($scope, elem, attrs, form) {
                window.onbeforeunload = function(){
                    if (form.$dirty) {
                        return "The form is dirty, do you want to stay on the page?";
                    }
                }
                $scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(event, next, current) {
                    if (form.$dirty) {
                        if(!confirm("The form is dirty, do you want to stay on the page?")) {
                            event.preventDefault();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        };
    });
```

With this I can guarantee that I have a good handle on the form controller because angular will throw an error if it cannot find a form controller on the element.

You can also add modifiers like **^** and **?** such as `require='^form'` to pull an ancestor form or `require='?form'` if the form is optional (this wont break the directive, but you will need to check that you have a handle on a valid form controller yourself).