# how to trigger onbeforeunload ($destroy)

Tags: angularjs

How to stop unload if some data changed and I have to do something before. I'm trying this, but no effect

```
$scope.changed = true;

$scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
   if ($scope.changed) {
     alert('Let me clean up first !');
     return ;
   }
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1jcsttm2/)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14852802/detect-unsaved-changes-and-alert-user-using-angularjs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This small code helps me out.

```
    $scope.changed = true;

    window.onbeforeunload = function(event){
     if ($scope.changed) {
       event.preventDefault();
       return ;
     }
   };
```