# check for unsaved form data in angularjs ( multiple forms using ui-router )

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-directive, angularjs-ng-form, jquery-dirtyforms

Implementation Details:

I'm using ui-router to load form page in ui-view div. I referred great example by [Andres Ekdahi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14852802/detect-unsaved-changes-and-alert-user-using-angularjs), How can i do $dirty check on multiple forms using same directive ?

form1

```
 <form name="myForm" ng-controller="Controller" confirm-on-exit>
```

form2

```
<form name="iForm" ng-controller="Controller" confirm-on-exit ng-model="myModel">
```

app.js ( directive )

```
myApp.directive('confirmOnExit', function() {
        return {
            link: function($scope, elem, attrs) {
                // condition when back page is pressed 
                window.onbeforeunload = function(){
                    if ($scope.myForm.$dirty) {
                        return "The formI is dirty, do you want to stay on the page?";
                    }
                }
                // condition when user try to load other form (via icons )
                $scope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, next, current) {
                    if ($scope.myForm.$dirty) {
                        if(!confirm("myForm. Do you want to continue ?")) {
                            event.preventDefault();
                        }
                    }

                    if ($scope.iForm.$dirty) {
                        if(!confirm("iform. Do you want to continue ?")) {
                            event.preventDefault();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        };
    });
```

Error:

First time on page load, the $dirty value is false. and I fill the form details and click third icon (file) and i get error for second form dirty check `if ($scope.iForm.$dirty)` and for `$dirty` in alert.

```
angular.js:12520 TypeError: Cannot read property '$dirty' of undefined
```

and

```
<form name="iForm" ng-controller="Controller" confirm-on-exit="" ng-model="myModel" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-scope">
```

Demo : [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/PlRCyuJrkoElU7XcDTfU?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make you directive more simpler by taking it from `name` attribute of `form`, so that only one condition will lie inside a directive & it can be reusable in many places.

```
<form name="myForm" ng-controller="Controller" confirm-on-exit>
```

**Code**

```
var form = $scope[attrs.name]; //which will take out form name & do search that inside scope
if (form.$dirty) { //form object would always exist, to make sure you could also add one more check `form &&`
    if(!confirm("myForm. Do you want to continue ?")) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

[**Demo here**](http://plnkr.co/edit/PlRCyuJrkoElU7XcDTfU?p=preview)

Comment: Can you explain me what does `$scope[attrs.name]` look for ? does this apply only for form data change or any user click ?

Comment: @Mad-D that will take out form name, and will search `formName` inside controller scope.

Comment: Thank you sir, I think that's exactly i needed to do.

Comment: Don't call me sir, I'm just like you. Glad to help you. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 2):

There's an easier way.

Just require your directive be placed on a form element and access the form controller through the link function:

```
myApp.directive('confirmOnExit', function() {
        return {
            require: 'form',
            link: function($scope, elem, attrs, formController) {
                // condition when back page is pressed 
                window.onbeforeunload = function(){
                    if (formController.$dirty) {
                        return "The form '" + formController.$name + "' is dirty, do you want to stay on the page?";
                    }
                }
                // condition when user try to load other form (via icons )
                $scope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, next, current) {
                    if (formController.$dirty) {
                        if(!confirm(formController.$name + ". Do you want to continue ?")) {
                            event.preventDefault();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        };
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

check if the form exists before you check if it is dirty.  Do something like

```
if ($scope.myForm && $scope.myForm.$dirty) {
    if(!confirm("myForm. Do you want to continue ?")) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}

if ($scope.iForm && $scope.iForm.$dirty) {
    if(!confirm("iform. Do you want to continue ?")) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, your answer is right as well. I just needed to check for form existence.