# Angular 1.5, component router detect unsaved changes and alert

Tags: angularjs, angular-component-router

When I use angular 1.3, I am used this ([Detect Unsaved changes and alert user using angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14852802/detect-unsaved-changes-and-alert-user-using-angularjs)) to detect unsaved change and alert to user, everything work fine. But when use angular 1.5 (component router) the value of `$ctrl.form.$dirty` was destroyed after `$locationChangeStart` so I can't get this value( before `$locationChangeStart`, this value show correctly when I debug by show it on the html code)

Anyone have suggestion
Thank so much!